# What is an easy way to share screen / voice chat on Linux?

Tags: linux, software-rec, arch-linux, screen-sharing, voice-chat

Currently I'm using Arch Linux. I'm more used to Linux now, but for communication, I still have some problems:

- My main software which I use on Windows is Skype and TeamViewer to share screen / voice chat to do pair programming with my friends.
- [imo.im](https://imo.im/) is too simple and it doesn't help much with only chat.

Is there any good way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Teamviewer is available for Linux: http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx
2. So is Skype: http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/

Comment: Is it available on 64bit system ? The last time I checked, they still used lib32

Comment: It should still run under 64-bit. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch64_FAQ#Can_I_run_32-bit_apps_inside_Arch64.3F and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_bundled_32-bit_system_in_Arch64

Comment: yup, with lib32. Thanks I will try it